# Hover one box and highlight another

Tags: html, css

```css
.first {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.first:hover .outer-box {
  background: black;
}
.outer-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <div class="first"></div>
</div>

<div class="outer-box"></div>
```

How can I hover over one box and highlight the other?

It would be easier if the boxes where in the same container but unfortunately they are not.

[Hope you can help perhaps updating my pen with no jquery if doable](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/zNzbvJ)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to affect other elements when a div is hovered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered)

Answer (score 2):

You can not manipulate an object that has no hierarchical level. You can use this method:

```
<div class="icons">
   <div class="first">
       <div class="outer-box"> </div>
   </div>
</div>

/* css */
.first:hover .outer-box{
    /* Your css code */
}
```

Or you can use javascript:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('first')[0].onmouseover = function(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('outer-box')[0].style = "background: black"
}

document.getElementsByClassName('first')[0].onmouseout = function(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('outer-box')[0].style = "background: green"
}
```

```css
.first{
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.outer-box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <div class="first">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer-box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this with the `+` **[combinator](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)**. Thing is, it needs to be a relative object, meaning - it must be at the same level in the html hierarchy.

You can read more about this selector **[here.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)**

[**Here is an update Pen.**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KaqEqQ)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method that uses a minimal amount of javascript.

```js
function color() {
  document.getElementById("outer").style.background = "black";
}
function outcolor() {
  document.getElementById("outer").style.background = "green";
}
```

```css
.first{
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.outer-box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <div class="first" onmouseover="color()" onmouseout="outcolor()">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer-box" id="outer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class="show someid" to an item and when you hover it it will hilight someid, or just add a class="show" and it will hilight the element found in the innerText of the hoverable.

```js
var show=document.getElementsByClassName('show')
for(var i=0;i<show.length;i=i+1){
 show[i].onmouseover = function(){
  var theclass=this.getAttribute('class');
  theclass=theclass.replace("show","");
  theclass=theclass.replace(" ","");
  if(theclass==''){
   var text=this.innerText;
  } else {
   var text=theclass;
  }
  document.getElementById(text).style = "background: #dddddd;"
 }
 show[i].onmouseout = function(){
  var theclass=this.getAttribute('class');
  theclass=theclass.replace("show","");
  theclass=theclass.replace(" ","");
  if(theclass==''){
   var text=this.innerText;
  } else {
   var text=theclass;
  }
  document.getElementById(text).style = "background: none;"
 }
}
```

```html
<p id="item1">This is item 1.</p>
<p id="item2">This is item 2.</p>
<hr>
<span class="show">item1</span>
<br>
<span class="show item2">Hover me to show item 2</span>
```